# Moving data from one partition to another

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-partitioning

I have a huge table containing about 500 million records. This table has 2 partitions, `CURRENT_DATA` and `PREVIOUS_DATA`.

When new data comes in, last `PREVIOUS_DATA` partition is truncated, and data from `CURRENT_DATA` partition is moved to `PREVIOUS_DATA` partition.

Right now, I am updating the records to move from one partition to another. However, it takes a long time. Is there any faster way to move data from one partition to another?

Comment: Do you have only two partitions? what is your partitioning key and type? Is where only one principle to define in witch partition data goes - is data previous or current?

Comment: Why do you move the partition data? Just truncate old partition and add new data.

Comment: There is an `ALTER TABLE… EXCHANGE PARTITION` and `ALTER TABLE… MOVE PARTITION` but I really don't see any reason for it. How does the table look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't strive to apply `DML`, but `DROP`, `RENAME` and `MODIFY` partitions as the partition `previous_data` is already been truncated such as

(*presuming you have a ***list partition*** with `VALUE = 'A'` for the current, and `VALUE = 'B'` for the previous partitions*)

```
ALTER TABLE tab 
DROP PARTITION previous_data; 

ALTER TABLE tab 
RENAME PARTITION current_data TO previous_data;

ALTER TABLE tab
MODIFY PARTITION previous_data
ADD VALUES ('B');

ALTER TABLE tab
MODIFY PARTITION previous_data
DROP VALUES ('A');

ALTER TABLE tab 
ADD PARTITION current_data VALUES ( 'A' );
```

Check out the partitions through

```
SELECT partition_name, high_value FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE table_name = 'TAB';
```

before and after applying those operations above(*both cases should return the same results*).

*Be careful! Those are dangerous operation and  shouldn't be tried within the production systems, but within the test databases !*

Comment: I'm getting this error while trying to execute alter table tab modify partition previous_data drop values ('A') statement.                                                                                           
14312. 00000 -  "Value %s already exists in partition %s"
*Cause:    One of the list values in the ADD PARTITION or ADD VALUES
           statement already exists in another partition
*Action:   Remove the duplicate value from the statement and try again

Comment: Have you created the table `tab` as `CREATE TABLE tab
(
  col1     varchar2(20)
)
PARTITION BY LIST(col1)
(
  PARTITION previous_data VALUES('B'),
  PARTITION current_data VALUES('A')
);`, then gradually applied those five steps ? @AbhinavDhiman

Answer (score 0):

If only goal is to separate current data from previous why not just to use two different tables PREVIOUS_DATA and CURRENT_DATA. You can easily get the complete picture by unioning the two together:

```
SELECT * FROM PREVIOUS_DATA
 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CURRENT_DATA
```

When new data comes you can drop PREVIOUS_DATA table, rename CURRENT_DATA to PREVIOUS_DATA and then create new empty CURRENT_DATA table:

```
DROP TABLE PREVIOUS_DATA;

ALTER TABLE CURRENT_DATA RENAME TO PREVIOUS_DATA;

CREATE TABLE CURRENT_DATA AS SELECT * FROM PREVIOUS_DATA WHERE 1 = 2; /*add comments and constraints*/
```

Comment: Why do you drop the table?

Comment: @ Wernfried Domscheit I do this instead of PREVIOUS_DATA partition truncating or dropping.

Comment: But there is only **one** table with two partitions.

Comment: @ Wernfried Domscheit I suggested to use two tables